# Java - HTTPS UTF8 and Post problems

Tags: java, post, utf-8, https, character-encoding

we are developping java application (Spring core, Spring mvc, Spring security, hibernate..., Tomcat7 and JDK7). 
We recently added a CAS server for SSO purpose. So we moved from http to https.

Now we have problems with utf8 encoding but only with POST method.

We have set this in the web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

What we have :

- ééé in the jsp source code is well displayed
- /myurl/mypage?data=ééé => request.getParameter("data") is well displayed
- but with an input in a form with POST method :  the data "ééé" is displayed like @Ec@Ec@Ec (i have not the result under my eyes).

the request.getCharacterEncoding() return UTF8.
We also check that encode file is UTF8.

I m lost. Have we missed something simple ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding as **ISO-8859-1** as i had resolved the same issue many times.

Comment: Thanks for your proposal Sanoop, but UTF 8 ensure universal communications.

We solved our problem and i m giving you the answer with a bit of shame : the encodingFilter need to be the first in the web.xml